# JavaScript: displaying a file in a text area:

Tags: javascript, file, textarea

I want to display the content of a file in a text area.
I use this script to do that but when I click in the open button the text doesn't appear:

```
   function loadFileAsText()
   {
    document.getElementById("textoNormal").scrollTop=0;
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent)
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("textoNormal").value =   textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
    id=1;
    }
```

textoNormal: is the id of my text area

Comment: Errors in console?

Comment: It works now :) But I don't know why some time it doesn't work. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: your code workes fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read file of content in **onChange** event of File Upload Control.

```
        function OnUpload() {
            var obj = document.getElementById("<%=FleUldLogo.ClientID%>");
            var source = obj.value;
            var file = obj.files[0];
            var textarea=$("#txtar");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
            textarea.value= reader.result;
             }
                    reader.readAsText(file);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can I have the right to modify my text in the text area with this code ?

Answer (score -1):

I called your function in a jQuery onClick and it worked well,

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.clickMe').click(function(){
    document.getElementById("textoNormal").scrollTop = 0;
            var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent)
            {
            var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                    document.getElementById("textoNormal").value = textFromFileLoaded;
            };
            fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
     id=1;        
    }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textoNormal"></textarea>
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" />

<div  class="clickMe">Click To Read Text File</div>
```

Comment: "it worked well" — Being unable to reproduce the problem doesn't solve the problem. This isn't an answer.

Comment: Ok, but some times it doesn't work.  I tried it again and it doesn't work

Comment: why minus, all time it working fine for me.. and you should at-least appreciate my ans, since i have tested/spent my time for you. for to help you.